# Scraping Error from 1mg AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' when using BeautifulSoup to extract text from an element

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from a webpage using BeautifulSoup in Python. Specifically, I want to extract the text content of an  element with the class "ProductTitle__product-title___3QMYH". However, I encountered the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.1mg.com/otc/durex-invisible-super-ultra-thin-condom-otc593647"


response = requests.get(url)


soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

product_title_element = soup.find("h1", {'class' :'ProductTitle__product-title___3QMYH'})


print(product_title_element.text)

if product_title_element is not None:
   product_title = product_title_element.text
   product_title = product_title.strip()
   print(product_title)
```

I have checked the HTML source of the webpage, and the  element with the specified class does exist. However, it seems that soup.find() is returning None, causing the error when trying to access the text attribute.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the type of the element of the respective class that you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

There are two obstacles to getting data from this page. The first is the protection of cloudflare, you can try to use [this](https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/) library, for example, but you still won't be able to get the data, because the page uses JS to generate content on the pages. I can offer such a solution using [this](https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/)  library.

At first:

```
pip install requests-html
```

Then:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession

url = "https://www.1mg.com/otc/durex-invisible-super-ultra-thin-condom-otc593647"

s = HTMLSession()
s.headers['user-agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36'
response = s.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

#Here you need to go all the way to the tag you are looking for.
product_title_element = soup.find_all("div", "col-sm-4")[3].find("h1", "ProductTitle__product-title___3QMYH").text

print(product_title_element)
```

Result:

```
Durex Invisible Super Ultra Thin Condom
```

I hope this solution will help you. Good luck.